# Check if some items are same in a c# list

Tags: c#, list, entity-framework, linq

I want to check if some items are same in a list based on a item present in the list.

```
List<ProductDetailDTO> productDTOs;
```

The ProductDetailDTO is -

```
public class ProductDetailDTO
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string GUID { get; set; }
    public string VariantName { get; set; }
    public string VariantValue { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to display all VariantName and VariantValue with the same GUIDs together.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you posted same question here as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52252391/display-fields-with-the-same-guids-together

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this

```
productDTOs.GroupBy(x => x.GUID,(key,item) => new
            {
                VariantName= item.Select(y=>y.VariantName),
                VariantValue = item.Select(y => y.VariantValue),

            }).ToList()
```

Comment: Minor recommendation to parse the guids.  Note they're stored in the DTO as a string right now.  Could be dupes uncaught.

Comment: @clarkitect Edited !!

Comment: How can I display all my variants with the same GUIDs together?

Comment: @mukeshkudi No it didn't. What I exactly want is to display the variants with the same GUIDs together.

Comment: @SuyashGupta Edited!!