# Display fields with the same GUIDs together

Tags: c#, list, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

I have a list of type ProductDetailDTO.

```
List<ProductDetailDTO> productDTOs;

public class ProductDetailDTO
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string GUID { get; set; }
    public string VariantName { get; set; }
    public string VariantValue { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

I have used linq to bind the data to the list.

```
var productDetails = (from product in ekartEntities.Products
                                  join productImage in ekartEntities.ProductImages on product.ProductId equals productImage.ProductId
                                  join category in ekartEntities.ProductCategories on product.Category equals category.CategoryId
                                  join mapping in ekartEntities.ProductVariantMappings on product.ProductId equals mapping.ProductId
                                  join variant in ekartEntities.ProductVariants on mapping.ProductVariantId equals variant.ProductVariantId
                                  join inventory in ekartEntities.Inventories on mapping.GUID equals inventory.Guid
                                  where product.ProductId == productDetailDTO.ProductId
                                  select new ProductDetailDTO()
                                  {
                                      ProductId = product.ProductId,
                                      Name = product.Name,
                                      Category = category.Name,
                                      Description = product.Description,
                                      Brand = product.Brand,
                                      Image = productImage.Image,
                                      GUID = mapping.GUID.ToString(),
                                      VariantName = variant.Name,
                                      VariantValue = mapping.Value,
                                      Price = inventory.Price
                                  }).ToList();
```

Now, I want to display all the variants (VariantName and VariantValue) with the same GUIDs together. How can I achieve that?

Comment: how did you bind data to list?

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "display **fields** together"?

Comment: @UdaraKasun Using linq. Updated the post!

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I want to display the columns of the list based on a column of the same list.

Comment: did you try to group by GUI

Comment: @UdaraKasun I can't. I have other fields also in select. That won't let me group by GUID only.

Comment: @Bizhan How can I use groupby only by GUID when I have many other column in the select clause?

Comment: So you mean to rearrange the columns?

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GroupBy and Select like this:

```
 var variants = productDTOs
                   .GroupBy(k => k.GUID)
                   .Select(v => v
                         .Select(variant => new 
                         {
                             variant.VariantName, 
                             variant.VariantValue
                         }));
```

Comment: Can I combine this variants with my existing productDTOs list?
Or can I do the grouping at the time of retrieving the other values from the db in productDTOs?

Comment: You can do both.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Group By

```
group p by p.GUID into g
select new { Id = g.Key, ProductDetail = g.ToList()).ToList();
```

If you have tables before group by, then you can add new object in the group itself

```
group new { p.xyz, n.xyz }
by new { p.GUID } into g
```

otherwise use **let** to save the intermediate object in an object and do grouping on it